# Binding to item from within group header style

Tags: c#, wpf

.xaml file

```
  <Window.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="xxxxx=" Background="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding mac_type}" Background="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                                <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"  IsReadOnly="True"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"  Margin="19,71,1,104" GridLinesVisibility="All">
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}" >
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <DataGridRowsPresenter></DataGridRowsPresenter>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

        </Grid>
```

.cs file

```
ListCollectionView Customers = new ListCollectionView(dt.DefaultView);
            Customers.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("mac_type"));
            DataGrid.ItemsSource = Customers;
```

This is my brief code.where i am binding datagrid with data.but my problem is in y group header (mac_type) not displaying any value.I dont not why its not binding mac_type,rest all works fine.Can anyone please help me solve.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind to `Name` instead of `mac_type` as defined in this example.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Yellow">
```

Link: http://cromwellhaus.com/2010/03/grouping-is-crazy-easy-in-wpf/